# Is http://www.shoutmeloud.com/videos a separate website?

Tags: wordpress, web

I just wondering whether http://www.shoutmeloud.com/videos is a subdomain under subdirectory?
I am just curious to know how we can do that.
I have a website called http://quantumbuddy.com/ and I want to share spirtual video the same way here shoutmeloud did.

Can anyone let me know how they did?

Comment: In what way is this a programming problem?

Comment: No, I dont know how they did that. I asked them but no respone. So I thought of asking here so that someone may suggest something to me.

Comment: In what way is this a *programming* problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website Shoutmeloud is a very popular website of a very popular Indian blogger Harsh Agarwal. The website is WordPress built as told by him many times. Regarding your question - the http://www.shoutmeloud.com/videos is not a directory because if it had been a WordPress directly there would be a login url - http://www.shoutmeloud.com/videos/wp-login.php, but it is not there.

Seeing the design of http://www.shoutmeloud.com/videos i think it is a post category (videos) which shows the post contained in it(here videos).

In wordpress this comes by default, all you have to do is to create a post category and add post in it. Then in these post add youtube videos embed code.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that by going to your wordpress dashboard then add a new page and name it like `videos` then insert some `video files` there whether it's a link or from your uploaded videos then save it.

To check the page, Add it to your main menu for example then save it.
The url would be like http://quantumbuddy.com/videos.

so basically the `videos` is the name of the page.

I checked your site and it only contain one link in the menu. Add a page and add it to your menu bar and it would display next to the `Blog` link.

> The website you are referring to is using Genesis Theme. You can find it [here](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/genesis/)
>   .

Comment: Wordpress has it's options to achieve that one.It depends on the theme you pick. explore the theme.

Comment: I edited my answer. see above and if it helps you may accept my answer.